# Verify on Telegram Test Environment

Tags: testing, telegram, environment

How to get verified badge in TTE?

Question about verifying account in Telegram Test Environment, how can I do? many accounts have verified badges with text i can do it by myself, but, i can't find how to do it. i checked a lot of documentations on telegram official website, api, some other websites such as https:// docs.pyrogram. org/topics/test-servers

I've already tried many variants but no one helps, so..

please help, where can i find documentation for telegram test environment.